# UI Automation + Mechanic.js: selector issue

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm using [Mechanic.js](http://www.cozykozy.com/mechanicjs/) framework with iOS UI Automation.

I have a cancel `UIBarButtonItem`. When I do this `$("#Cancel").index()`, the result is `-1` which is not found. Am I missing something here? Just to clarify, `$("#Cancel")` does work by itself but `.index()` won't able to retrieve the right index.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Apple broke the equality operation on UIAElements (see also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12100928/2063546)), which Mechanic.js relied on in order to figure out the index of a found element.